# Why is an array limited by size, when I can initialize values to indices out of its bounds?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to understand the concept of a fixed size in an array. Consider the following array:

```
int arr[1] = {0};
```

Now, if I subscript `arr` by any unsigned value greater than `0`, I will get undefined values.

But if I do:

```
arr[1] = 42;
```

Now index `1` of `arr` holds `42`. I can keep doing this assignment to any index of `arr`, making `arr` hold more than one `int`, which it was originally defined as.

How is `arr` having a fixed size if I can keep assigning multiple `int`s to its indices?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (also called UB). When you go out of bounds you will have UB. Just don't do it.

Comment: @ArminMontigny: Pretty new to C++! Guess I should have searched more diligently though (somehow it didn't cross my mind that the reassignment would be undefined behaviour!).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: Thanks so much, that clears it up! I was under the impression that accessing out-of-bounds indices would lead to just *undefined values* (which could be *made defined* by assignment).

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `arr[1] = 42;` is not initialization; it's assignment. Initialization occurs when you **create** an object, as in `int arr[1] = {0};`. Yes, that initialization uses `=`, which makes it look similar to assignment, but `int arr[1] = {0};` does not use the assignment operator.